# Accessing a column named Cast in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table and one of the columns is named CAST. How can I access this column. I've tried
`Select [Cast] AS cast_s FROM tablename` without success, Can I use this name or must I reimport all my data into bigquery?

I know that cast is a function. This is the error message:

**Error:**

> Encountered " "CAST" "Cast "" at line 10, column 63. Was expecting: < E O F > (EOF has no spaces, markdown makes it disappear)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexical rules for BQ use backticks for this purpose:

```
select `cast` as cast_s
from tablename;
```

The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/lexical).

Answer (score 0):

For BigQuery Legacy SQL you CAN use square brackets

```
SELECT [cast] as cast_s
FROM tablename
```

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#select)

> You can use square brackets to escape reserved words so that you can
>   use them as field name and aliases. For example, if you have a column
>   named "prefix", which is a reserved word in BigQuery syntax, the
>   queries referencing that field will fail with obscure error messages
>   unless you escape it with square brackets:
>
> SELECT [prefix] FROM ...

Comment: So exactly what I put in my question.

Comment: exactly! it works in Legacy SQL mode - so you should double check!